# Detect when someone use an emoji in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made a function in a discord bot that will delete user message, when its lenght is past 100 characters, animated/custom/unicode emojis however bypasses this 100 characters limit (theoretically, 1 emoji is not equal to 1 character, idk how it works) but my bot crash after to many of them. I want to make a function, that will detect these emojis, and if it finds one, just delete this person comment. I was working on something like that.

```
client.on('messageCreate', message =>{ 
  if(message.content.startsWith(":") && message.content.endsWith(":") || message.content.startsWith("<:") && message.content.endsWith(":>") {
    return;
  }
  else {
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot || message.member.roles.cache.has('828277437242146816')) return;
```

If you have any other solution, you can share it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

All emojis in Discord start with `<:` (animated emojis start with `<:a`) and end with `:>`. Between these group of characters is the emoji name aswell as it's ID. You can use `String.prototype.match()` to match regex with a string, thus finding an emoji. You can read more about the method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). Using `message.content.startsWith("<:")` and `message.content.endsWith(":>")` isn't reliable as messages don't often start with emojis.

Comment: Animated emotes start with `<a:`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't awear of that. I'll edit my answer.